# Clonezilla installation - Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 16.10, clonezilla

I'm trying to install clonezilla, but I got an error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clonezilla is already the newest version (3.21.13-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up clonezilla (3.21.13-1) ...
ln: target '/opt/' is not a directory: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package clonezilla (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clonezilla
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could anyone be able to tell what could I do to fix this problem?

**P.S.** I'm using Ubuntu gnome 16.10.

Comment: Could you please assure that `/opt/` exists (e. g. with `sudo mkdir -p /opt`) and try again? What's the result?

Comment: Yes, that works. I did that previously, and It seems that it was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `/opt` directory manually and try again:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I'd actually classify this as a bug because the package post-installation script assumes blindly that such a directory exists even though that is not the case on a default Ubuntu (or Debian) installation.

If you want to be nice and support free open-source software like Clonezilla, please file a bug report with the maintainer of the package in question.